# Pandas: split column into smaller ones based on another column's values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following Pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame({'Status': ['Draft', 
   'Active','Completed','Completed', 'Draft', 'Active'], 'Region': 
   ['Europe','Europe', 'Asia','Australia', 'Asia', 'Australia'],'Budget': [1000,
   2000,3000,4000,5000,6000]})
```

I am grouping and aggregating it as follows:

```
grouped_by_region = df.groupby('Region').agg({'Budget':sum})
```

So the output of `print(grouped_by_region)` is:

```
Region    Budget

Asia         8000
Australia   10000
Europe       3000
```

What I want to do is split the budget column into "Budget draft", "Budget active", "Budget completed" columns. So basically I need to create new columns based 'Status' column values and rename them accordingly.

How to achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe

Comment: In this case, `df.pivot_table('Budget', 'Region', 'Status', np.sum)`

Comment: See the answer to question #4 https://stackoverflow.com/a/47152692/2336654

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can just add `Status` to your groupby and unstack:

```
df.groupby(['Region', 'Status']).agg({'Budget':sum}).unstack(fill_value=0)

          Budget                
Status    Active Completed Draft
Region                          
Asia           0      3000  5000
Australia   6000      4000     0
Europe      2000         0  1000
```

Though the `pivot` solutions proposed in the comments work just as well